# Getting number of fouls per team per year for soccer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the number of red-card fouls per team per year for soccer.

Here is my sample data, followed by the DDL+DML.

soccer_team

| team_id | team_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Team A |
| 2 | Team B |
| 3 | Team C |

match

| match_id | match_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2018 |
| 2 | 02-03-2018 |
| 3 | 05-04-2018 |
| 4 | 01-01-2018 |
| 5 | 02-02-2019 |
| 6 | 07-04-2019 |
| 7 | 06-13-2019 |
| 8 | 08-18-2019 |
| 9 | 03-01-2020 |
| 10 | 06-02-2020 |
| 11 | 09-03-2020 |
| 12 | 12-04-2020 |

foul

| foul_id | team_id | match_id | foul_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Y |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | Y |
| 3 | 3 | 10 | Y |
| 4 | 3 | 10 | R |
| 5 | 2 | 11 | Y |
| 6 | 2 | 11 | R |
| 7 | 3 | 11 | R |
| 8 | 3 | 11 | R |

DDL+DML:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.soccer_team (
    team_id   int         NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    team_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_soccer_team PRIMARY KEY ( team_id )
);

CREATE TABLE dbo."match" (
    match_id   int  NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    match_date date NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_match PRIMARY KEY ( match_id )
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.foul (
    foul_id   int     NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    team_id   int     NOT NULL,
    match_id  int     NOT NULL,
    foul_type char(1) NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_foul PRIMARY KEY ( foul_id ),

    CONSTRAINT FK_foul_match FOREIGN KEY(match_id) REFERENCES dbo.match (match_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_foul_soccer_team FOREIGN KEY(team_id) REFERENCES dbo.soccer_team (team_id)
);
    
----

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.soccer_team ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo."match" ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.foul ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.soccer_team ( team_id, team_name )
VALUES
(1, 'Team A'),
(2, 'Team B'),
(3, 'Team C');

INSERT INTO dbo.match ( match_id, match_date )
VALUES
(1, '01-01-2018'),
(2, '02-03-2018'),
(3, '05-04-2018'),
(4, '01-01-2018'),
(5, '02-02-2019'),
(6, '07-04-2019'),
(7, '06-13-2019'),
(8, '08-18-2019'),
(9, '03-01-2020'),
(10, '06-02-2020'),
(11, '09-03-2020'),
(12, '12-04-2020');

INSERT INTO dbo.foul (foul_id, team_id, match_id, foul_type )
VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Y'),
(2, 3, 5, 'Y'),
(3, 3, 10, 'Y'),
(4, 3, 10, 'R'),
(5, 2, 11, 'Y'),
(6, 2, 11, 'R'),
(7, 3, 11, 'R'),
(8, 3, 11, 'R');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.soccer_team OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo."match" OFF;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.foul OFF;
```

I can do some basic stuff like getting the number of red card fouls per team or per year:

```
SELECT
    YEAR( match_date ) AS yearly_season,
    COUNT( foul_type ) AS total_red_cards 
FROM
    dbo.foul AS df
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.match AS dm ON
        df.match_id = dm.match_id
        AND
        df.foul_type = 'R'

GROUP BY
    YEAR( match_date )
```

and

```
SELECT
    team_name,
    COUNT( foul_type ) AS total_red_cards 

FROM
    dbo.foul AS df
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.soccer_team AS dst ON
        df.team_id = dst.team_id
        AND
        df.foul_type = 'R'

GROUP BY
    team_name
```

Which work just fine, including teams or years with ZERO red fouls. Getting results like:

| Year | Total red cards |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | 0 |
| 2019 | 0 |
| 2020 | 4 |

and

| Team | Total red cards |
| --- | --- |
| Team A | 0 |
| Team B | 1 |
| Team C | 3 |

But I am unable to get the following which is my requirement:

| Year | Team | Total red cards |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Team A | 0 |
| 2018 | Team B | 0 |
| 2018 | Team C | 0 |
| 2019 | Team A | 0 |
| 2019 | Team B | 0 |
| 2019 | Team C | 0 |
| 2020 | Team A | 0 |
| 2020 | Team B | 1 |
| 2020 | Team C | 3 |

Instead, I am getting the following using queries like:

```
SELECT
    YEAR( match_date ) AS yearly_season,
    team_name, 
    COUNT( foul_type ) AS total_red_cards

FROM
    dbo.foul AS df
    INNER JOIN dbo.soccer_team AS dst ON
        df.team_id = dst.team_id
        AND
        df.foul_type = 'R'

    RIGHT JOIN dbo.match AS dm ON
        df.match_id = dm.match_id

GROUP BY
    YEAR( match_date ),
    team_name
```

| Year | Team | Total red cards |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | NULL | 0 |
| 2019 | NULL | 0 |
| 2020 | NULL | 0 |
| 2020 | Team B | 1 |
| 2020 | Team C | 3 |

or

| Year | Team | Total red cards |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Team B | 1 |
| 2020 | Team C | 3 |

Or worse even, if I use JOINS starting from Fouls all the way to Matches (the numbers don't add up):

| Year | Team | Total red cards |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | NULL | 0 |
| 2019 | NULL | 0 |
| 2020 | NULL | 0 |
| 2020 | Team B | 3 |
| 2020 | Team C | 12 |

Maybe some sub-queries might do the job? Or there is a problem with database structure?

Comment: @Dale K Sorry. I added a lot of tables and a code. I hope is clearer this time around. Thanks.

Comment: @DaleK Done. I tried stuff like SQLFiddle to make it easier to read and more compact, but they kept giving problems so this is the end result. Now... would you please?

Comment: Great work on improving your question BTW... that definitely encourages people to assist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it. For situations like this, where this isn't a datapoint for all the results you want returned, you have to first build the required resultset - in this case using a `CROSS JOIN` of the teams and the years.

Then, once you have the desired rows you can use a sub-query for each row to obtain the red card fouls.

```
SELECT Y.MatchYear, T.team_name
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM #foul F
        INNER JOIN #match M ON M.match_id = f.match_id
        WHERE F.team_id = T.team_id AND YEAR(M.match_date) = Y.MatchYear AND F.foul_type = 'R'
    )
FROM #soccer_team T
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR([match_date]) MatchYear
    FROM #match
    GROUP BY YEAR([match_date])
) Y
ORDER BY Y.MatchYear ASC, T.team_name ASC;
```

Note I used temp tables as I didn't want permanent tables in my database, so just change the table names.

Comment: Thank you so much. Took me some time to understand what you did. But now i know and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Dale's solution (which is perfectly fine). Since you want to count rows that does not exists (team that does not have a foul one year), you need to "construct" the domain (all team, all years) somehow. `CROSS JOIN` is the SQL lingo for the cartesian product between two sets:

```
select *
from dbo.[match] m
cross join dbo.soccer_team t
```

We call this relation x in lack of a better word:

```
from ( 
  select *
  from dbo.[match] m
  cross join dbo.soccer_team t
) as x
```

Now we can join this with foul to get the year, the teamname and the related cards. Note that we need an outer join since all teams don't have a foul each year:

```
select year(x.match_date), x.team_name
     , f.foul_type
from ( 
  select *
  from dbo.[match] m
  cross join dbo.soccer_team t
) as x
left join dbo.foul f
    on f.match_id = x.match_id
    and f.team_id = x.team_id
```

Instead of adding a filter in a WHERE clause, we can use it in an aggregate function. `COUNT(x)` counts all x that are not null. Absent rows are already null, so we need to handle cards other than 'R'

```
case when f.foul_type = 'R' then 1 end
```

Will map all foul_type other than 'R' to null, hence they will not be considered by COUNT:

```
select year(x.match_date), x.team_name
     , count(case when f.foul_type = 'R' then 1 end) 
from ( 
  select *
  from dbo.[match] m
  cross join dbo.soccer_team t
) as x
left join dbo.foul f
    on f.match_id = x.match_id
    and f.team_id = x.team_id
group by year(x.match_date), x.team_name
order by year(x.match_date), x.team_name
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iisZIr7j) I added a modified (removed #) version of Dale's solution

BTW, well done with improving your post. Without the DDL I would never have considered answering the question. If you want to improve your future posts even more you can add a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Definitely performs better than my solution.